# FileSystem watcher path is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have created C# windows service to monitor the active directory password changes. Whenever password changes, the service will call a webservice and return result. If service returns not returns success, the filewatcher directry create a textfile for the that; otherwise not. When service starts, if there is any pending request, it will process.

```
//Whenever file created... Synchronize the pending requests. When active direcory changes occur it will create files. If request is suucessfull delte the created file otherwise not
```

When I change the  `path. The Filewatchercreated event is not firing. Like changing passwords with any other name Data or something like that. If anyone can please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Have you check so the that the folder you are trying to access don't require administration rights?

Comment: Frozendragon thanks for the reply. I have checked that. Both files are created using code and having same permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to set the notify filters somewhere?

I can't see where your creating the watcher but It could be that:

```
NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.Attributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

with all of the annoying issues I have had over the past with the filewatcher, like this one, I  have done away with it in all of my code and gone back to the trusty old timer and poll the directory. It's worked 100% of the time for me and picks p the files when the service was not running. I hope that helps.

Comment: Please let me know is there any other solution for this proble. Because I am editing one part of already existing project...

Comment: I have to note that I have the complete opposite experience. Filewatcher works great! Only caveats I've seen with it are well documented. Such as, you have to manually trigger on EXISTING files if they are already there before your filewatcher is registered. And the filesystem the files are on support it and fall within the domain of the system security (ie, local filesystem on individual machine, domain member on a network machine with proper AD permissions in filesystem). And with enterprise level software using this feature to process several hundreds and up per day, I see no problem!